# Sed command to add line of text to the very end of a file

Tags: macos, bash, sed

I want to use sed to add a line of text to the very end of a file. In this case I am working on OS X and I want to add a line in the /etc/sudoers files. I want my string to be the last string in the file on its own line. Any ideas?

Example:

```
text 
text 
text
<my string>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

If you can do it without sed it would be easy enough to do `echo <line> >> /etc/sudoers` (though be careful that you have a valid line!).

If you want do it with sed you could do `sed -i -e '$a<line>' /etc/sudoers` to go to the last line then append your text.

Comment: echo command does not work for the /etc/sudoers file it says that the permission is denied... Also I tried the sed command and it give me a "sed: 1: "$atty_tickets : command a expects \ followed by text"

Comment: @Technic1an, You need to use `sudo`.

Comment: @Technic1an, The `/etc/sudoers` file by default is read only, so you need to first use `chmod` to make it writable.

Comment: @Eric Renouf, BSD `sed`, unlike GNU `sed` requires an argument to the `-i` option.  Can be either an extension or `''`, e.g. `sed -i .bak ...` or `sed -i '' ...`. The latter of which does it in place.

Comment: @user3439894 huh, I did not know that, thanks for the heads up.

Comment: You can pipe it to tee:
`echo "line to add" | sudo tee -a /etc/sudoers`

Answer (score 3):

Consider using `echo` and output redirection:

```
sudo sh -c "echo 'my string' >> /etc/sudoers"
```

.

Comment: echo command does not work for the /etc/sudoers file it says that the permission is denied

Comment: @Technic1an: I made an edit to introduce the `sudo` command to run this as an administrator.  To get the redirect to work through a `sudo`, we need to run a shell and provide it a mini-shell-script via the `-c` option.

Comment: @ctt, I didn't see what you had posted and now that I have I've deleted my answer as your's is much safer! :) +1

Answer (score 3):

You can use `awk`

```
awk '1; END {print "text to add"}' file > tmp && mv tmp file
```

This will add `text to add` as a new line at the end of file `file`

Answer (score 1):

I have also tried to achieve this using sed, but unfortunately, haven't found any solution yet. But I have found a workaround to achieve this using echo:

$ echo "the line you want to add" >> yourTextFile.txt